# Rails fields_for parameters for a has_many relation don't yield an Array in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, fields-for

I have a model Sensor with `has_many` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` relationships to another model Watch. In a form to update a Sensor, I have something like the following

```
<%= sensor_form.fields_for :watches do |watches_form| %>
   <%= watches_form.label :label %><br />
   <%= watches_form.text_field :label %>
<% end %>
```

This is indended to allow editting of the already-created Watches belonging to a Sensor.

This call spits form inputs as so:

```
<input name="sensor[watches_attributes][0][label]" ... />
<input name="sensor[watches_attributes][0][id]" ... />
```

When this gets submitted, the `params` object in the Sensor controller gets an assoc like

```
"sensor" => {
  "id"=>"1",
   "watches_attributes"=> { 
     "0"=>{"id" => "1", "label" => "foo"},
     "1"=>{"id" => "2", "label" => "bar"}
   }
}
```

For a `has_many`, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` update to work upon the `@sensor.update_attributes` call, it seems that that attributes key really must map to an Array.

From what I've seen in the examples, the combination of `has_many`, `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, and `sensor_form.fields_for` should allow me to pass the resulting `params` object directly to `@sensor.update_attributes` and update each related object as intended. Instead the Sensor takes place, with no errors, but the Watch objects are not updated (since `"watches_attributes"` maps to a Hash instead of an Array?) Have I missed something?

Comment: Basically `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is magic and does all of that, including transforming the [`Hash` into an usable `Array`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8510a0bb5a8a65e4bc067ee5a7d98aae965b47a5/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L382) for you. That being said I don't know why your `Watch` objects aren't saving properly.

Comment: Ok. Then I guess this is probably due to there being something wrong with the attributes themselves. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From rails 3 you also need to add

```
attr_accessible :watches_attributes
```

to your Sensor class